# How can I rewrite this code to work faster?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following nested loop. Basically, it counts the number of simultaneous occurances of i and j in various lists (m), and if they both do indeed exists in it, counts the number of times they simultaneously exist (n) in another set of lists.

```
C = np.zeros((N,N))
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i+1,N):
            n = 0
            m = 0
            for p in partitions:
                if(i in p["indices"] and j in p["indices"]):
                    m += 1
                    if(p["groups"][list(p["indices"]).index(i)] == p["groups"][list(p["indices"]).index(j)]):
                        n +=1
            C[i][j] = n/m
```

"partitions" consists of 100 dictionaries and N = 150, so it takes quite a while for this code to finish. Is there any way of speeding this up?

Comment: How many items are typically in `p["indices"]` And what type of data structure is it? For one thing, you are searching for the existence of `i` twice, once in the `i in p["indices"]` part and once in `list(p["indices"]).index(i)`. I think you should be able to do it with just one search for the index.

Comment: Around 150. It is just a list.

Comment: 2nd, depending on what type of data structure `p["indices"]` is, there may be a faster way to search other than a linear search. For example if those items are already sorted...

Comment: Can you provide some sample data for the partitions variable.  It's very hard to figure out anything concrete without that.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote several things but this is a better idea:

At the moment you are repeatedly doing a search using `for in blah` and `blah.index()`. Besides the fact that one search could be done to account for those two, there's also repetition because values of `i` and `j` overlap, leading to multiple searches for the same values. You can do all this one time up front and save the results in a dictionary and then just look them up later.

At the beginning of the code you can do a loop. Something like:

```
searches = dict()
for p in partitions:
    #Assuming p isn't repeated
    searches[p] = dict()
    for i in range(N):
       try: 
           searches[p] = p["indices"].index(i)
       except ValueError:
           pass

C = np.zeros((N,N))
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i+1,N):
            n = 0
            m = 0
            for p in partitions:
                if (searches[p].get(i) and searches[p].get(j)):
                    m += 1
                    if(p["groups"][searches[p].get(i)] == p["groups"][searches[p].get(j)]):
                        n +=1
            C[i][j] = n/m
```

I'm a little fuzzy on whether using `p` as your dictionary key is a good idea, since I'm not sure of the type. If not, you can create a p_index to use like `searches[p_index]`, but then you have to alter both `for p in partitions` loops and make sure they use the same p_index order. Hope that makes sense.

There's probably also a way to use [bisect](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-bisect-in-python/) instead of the `index()` calls at the top if the `p["indices"]` lists are already sorted. For what it's worth I *think* it's still faster to take the time to sort them up front and do a bisect than to do linear searches with it unsorted.

Comment: Thanks. They are not sorted atm but i can sort them, it won't be a problem.
I guess you meant `if(i_idx> -1 and j_idx > -1):`  instead of i and j?

Comment: Ah, yes you're right I did. I think the new answer is better though.

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster to write the loop "inside out". I.e. have the loop through `partitions` as the outermost loop? Then as a first step calculate all the `p["groups"][searches[p].get(k)]` for all possible `k` and store them in an array. `n` and `m` could be 2D arrays which get divided at the end.